# Remove dynamic array of keys from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked through articles and SO questions for the last hour and still can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a single dimensional string array containing containing keys from my multidimensional array. Both arrays are dynamic. I need a way to remove every key in the 1D from the MD array.

It's hard to explain, so let me just show you.

```
$dynamicKeys = ['date', 'name', 'account'];

$arrayRequiringSanitization = [
  'name' => [
    'first' => 'Homer',
    'last' => 'simpson'
  ],
  'age' => 'unknown',
  'facts' => [
    'history' => [
      'date' => 'whenever',
      'occurred' => 'nope'
    ],
    'is' => 'existing'
  ]
];

function removeDynamicValues($arr, $vals) {
  // this is where i need help
}
```

The `removeDynamicValues` function should take the `$arrayRequiringSanitization` and `$dynamicKeys` and return an array that looks as follows:

```
$arrayRequiringSanitization = [
  'age' => 'unknown',
  'facts' => [
    'history' => [
      'occurred' => 'nope'
    ],
    'is' => 'existing'
  ]
];
```

So basically, it removed the `name` sub array and the `date` sub sub property. The important part is that both arrays are dynamic, and it's not known how deep `$arrayRequiringSanitization` will be nested.

Let me know if I need to provide further clarrification.

Comment: Using the technique from the duplicate: https://3v4l.org/64P8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with recursion. Here's the code.

```
/**
 * @param array<mixed> $arr initial array
 * @param array<string|int> $vals array of keys that need to be deleted
 * @return array<mixed>
 */
function removeDynamicValues(array $arr, array $vals): array
{
    $out = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $vals, true)) {
            $out[$key] = is_array($value) ? removeDynamicValues($value, $vals) : $value;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```